# Creating a database for employees where the first 3 values don't count

Tags: mysql

I am creating a database that holds information about employee errors for a presentation.

- One table will contain the errors and the error ID (there are 64 categories),
- while others will contain the employee, the error ID, the number of errors under each category, the months 1-12 for each error, and the total number of errors.

However, with each error and error category that is recorded, it will not count toward the total until after the third error. I need to be able to query this data for an accurate count of all errors in all error categories, with the first three errors in each category not counting in the total. What's the easiest way to do this?

For example, In January, Employee 1 made 14 errors in category 1, 4 errors in category 2, and 8 errors in category 3. The total number of errors would be (14-3) + (4-3) + (8-3) = 17 errors.
I've tried arithmetic functions but are too lengthy for any real efficiency and need an easier way (generalized)

Comment: Use `IF(error_count < 3, 0, error_count - 3) AS errors`

Comment: Are those tables populated simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take into account only errors greater than 3 you could filter as Barmar says, but without subtracting the 3:

```
if(error_counter < 3, 0, error_counter) as errors
```